# A polygon has 60 diagonals. How many sides does it have?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, polygons

I've used this formula to calculate the solution.

> The number of diagonals of a polygon is $(n(n-3))/2$, where $n$ is the number of sides of a polygon.

But I'm getting answer as decimal point. Is the question wrong or am I doing any calculation mistake?

Comment: Sorry about that. The question is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the question is worded wrongly. In any polygon, the number of diagonals is one less than a triangular number, and 60+1=61 is not triangular.

In three dimensions, a regular dodecahedron has 60 face diagonals, plus 100 internal (body) diagonals.

Comment: Another way to see it can't be 60 is that the number of diagonals can't be divisible by 3 without also being divisible by 9.